# Spring bean scope Tenant cannot be resolved by Intellij

Tags: spring, scope, intellij-idea, configuration-files, sap-commerce-cloud

My Intellij IDE tells me that the scope "tenant" of my Bean Definition cannot be resolved.

Although it doesn't stop me from deploying and running my application, it looks kinda messy. Is there a way for me to tell Intellij how to resolve this?

I've tried adding **coreserver.jar**, which is the jar that contains the **TenantScope** class, to my module's dependencies, but that didn't work.

The error is being shown by Intellij's inspection **'Spring Scopes'**. I have to let this inspection know somehow that the Tenant Scope is declared in an XML file in another module. I've also tried adding this other module as a dependency of the **petsplacecore** module, but that didn't work either.

Here's what my screen looks like:

[image]

The Tenant scope is declare in the module **yacceleratorstorefront**, in the file **web-application-config.xml**, like this:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="tenant" value="de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Where is the scope actually defined?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Not sure, where should it usually be defined? Is it something that should be on my classpath but might not be?

Comment: "tenant" is not a standard bean scope, so I assume it's provided by some framework or library you're using. Perhaps Grails, or Camel? What does scoping a bean as "tenant" actually do (in your application)?

Comment: You're right, it's not. It's a Hybris scope I think. I'm not actually sure what it means for a Bean, to have that scope. If I search for a Type, I can see many classes that include Tenant in their name. Can you help me find out how the Scope is defined?

Comment: Is the Hybris library available for download somewhere?

Comment: Another thing to try: look up type _org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope_ in your project classpath, and then navigate to implementations (Ctrl-Alt-B). Do you see any implementation outside of the default ones provided by Spring itself? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I add the 2 Spring Configuration files to the same Fileset in Petsplacecore's Spring Facet, then the reference to the Tenant Scope declaration can be found.

As shown on the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The "tenant" scope is a bespoke hybris scope, defined in the web-application-config.xml as:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="tenant" value="de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And you should be able to find it in platform/ext/core/bin/coreserver.jar - add this jar to your classpath.
And there ends my knowledge of IntelliJ, I'm afraid...

Comment: Hi DrUseful,
You're right about the declaration and the jar that contains the TenantScope class, but adding the jar to my classpath didn't help. 

The error is being shown by Intellij's inspection 'Spring Scopes'. I have to let this inspection know somehow that the Tenant Scope is declared in an XML in another module. I've also tried adding this other module as a dependency of my petsplacecore module, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

As of hybris 5.0, the custom "tenant" scope is no longer needed in your spring configuration files and thus there is no need to get Intellj IDEA to acknowledge this custom scope.